# Placing a uniqueness constraint on a date range

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.3, range-types, exclusion-constraint

I have a table `reservation` with columns `roomno(INTEGER)`, `startdate(DATE)`, `enddate(DATE)` with a primary key on (`roomno, startdate`).

How do I place a constraint on the table such that bookings are not allowed to overlap?

I am trying to implement this in [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15) postgreSQL9.3

For example:

```
101  2016-01-01   2016-01-05
101  2016-01-03   2016-01-06 [This row should not be possible to insert]
```

`startdate` and `enddate` are data type `date`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [**exclusion constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT) and be aware how bounds for the type `daterange` work. `date` is a discrete type, so ranges have default `[)` bounds. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE)

> The built-in range types `int4range`, `int8range`, and `daterange` all use a
> canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper
> bound; that is, `[)`.

So, to book a room from 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-05, including first and last day, you have to specify bounds explicitly:

```
daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]')
```

Or you enter dates with *exclusive* upper bounds; to include 2016-01-05, enter 2016-01-**06**. Then you can use the simpler expression:

```
daterange(start_date, end_date)
```

***Either*** create a functional index with the above expression in the exclusion constraint, like demonstrated here:

- [Uniqueness constraint with date range](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110582/uniqueness-constraint-with-date-range)

This way you can keep columns like you have right now.

***Or*** you can replace `startdate` and `enddate` with a `daterange` column and use the plain column in the exclusion constraint. Like in this related answer:

- [Updating table of versioned rows with historical records in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95845/updating-table-of-versioned-rows-with-historical-records-in-postgresql/96030#96030)

In any case, assuming `roomno` is an `integer` column, you need to install the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) first, once per database. See:

- [Combining separate ranges into largest possible contiguous ranges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100965/combining-separate-ranges-into-largest-possible-contiguous-ranges/101010#101010)
- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505869/939860)