# Postgres unique constraint with a custom comparator

Tags: postgresql, schema

TLDR: Is it possible to add a unique constraint to a column in a Postgres table that will use a custom comparison operator or function to compare the newly inserted or modified column with the rest of the table to guarantee uniqueness.

For my project, I have a table of network IP ranges, and I am using the iprange type from [github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r) postgres extension. That extension supports storing arbitrary network IP ranges, which can be of any size and need fall precisely on CIDR boundaries.

In my database design, I want there to be an error if the application attempts to insert a row describing an iprange that overlaps with any existing iprange in the table. The ip4r extension provides the `&&` operator that can test if two IP ranges overlap.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM net_table WHERE network && '192.168.1.3-192.168.1.7'::iprange
```

Is there a way to express the restriction as a unique index or constraint on my table somehow? Or do I have to do the check in the application before each insert or update ?

Comment: What you want is not a unique, but an [exclusion constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140024/placing-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-a-date-range)